# Lightbox close within body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

My client requires that a lightbox is opened on click anywhere within the page. So I have created a function and called it in body using the `onclick` event.

Javascript:

```
function openLighbox(){
  $('a.html5lightbox').trigger('click');
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onclick="openLighbox()">
  <a class="html5lightbox" href="form.html"><img src="cmDest.jpg"></a>
</body>
```

From the above code, I have successfully opened the lightbox, but when I try to close the lightbox it can't be closed since the click opens it again.

My question is that how can I prevent it opening again?

Comment: After closing the lightbox, What should happen when you click again on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

trigger the click only if the element is not the lightbox ,renmove the onclick attribute

```
$('body').click(function(e){
 console.log(e.target)
if ( !$(e.target).closest('#html5box-html5-lightbox').length) {

                    $('a.html5lightbox').trigger('click');
        } 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oxtr7me0/

Comment: When I clicked on close button. Once again light box open.

Comment: can you provide a link to the lightbox documentation?

Comment: Still same situation

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I am going for lunch. Thank you for spent time.